# What does this juggling gesture usually mean?

Tags: body-language

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=LyCwXLDr_-0#t=187s

I notices not first time in chaotic context.. it seems people reproducing gesture have chaos

Comment: Sorry, Xsi, but I can't understand what is being asked here. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: It seems like the OP is asking about the meaning of a gesture which looks like the speaker is "juggling" something. The posted video illustrates the gesture at minute 3:08. The context seems to be "confusion" (I guess this is what is meant by "chaos"). The question is certainly mistagged as "sign-languages" and also doesn't seem on-topic for Linguistics. Perhaps over at English Language & Usage?

Comment: The OP is having difficulties there, too. They've recommended transferring some questions here.

Comment: I don't know a site where "body language" would be fit. Linguistics seems the best for this, but the question is really poorly worded. If Xsi could add some more explanations, it would certainly help. @lapropriu You're right about the tag, I'll change it.

Comment: The essential points I think should be included in the question are: **(1)** In what culture/language? Gestures are not international, so indications about that should be specified. **(2)** Indicate also the exact time the gesture starts in the video. ... I can't think of something else for now. :P

Comment: Video material link ending with #t=187s (link has precise pointing time).